# If $\mu$ is a signed measure, can we show that $\left\{A\in\mathcal A:\mu(A)\ge0\right\}$ is a monotone class?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space
- $\mu$ be a real-valued measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$

> Are we able to show that $$\mathcal M:=\left\{A\in\mathcal A:\mu(A)\ge0\right\}$$ is a monotone class?

Let $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal M$ and $A:=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$. We need to show that $A\in\mathcal M$. Let $$B_n:=\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i$$$$C_1:=B_1\;,\;\;\;C_{n+1}:=B_{n+1}\setminus B_n=A_{n+1}\setminus B_n$$ $(B_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is nondecreasing and $$A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}B_n=\biguplus_{n\in\mathbb N}C_n\;.$$ We've clear got $$\mu(C_{n+1})=\mu(B_{n+1})-\mu(B_n)\;.$$ So, it seems like we need to show $$0\le\mu(B_n)\le\mu(B_{n+1})\;.$$

> Can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oops:** I said

No, the set where $\mu\ge0$ need not even be closed under finite unions. Say $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $\mu(\{j\})=c_j$, $c_1=-2$, $c_2=3$, $c_3=-2$. Let $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$; then $\mu(A),\mu(B)>0$, $\mu(A\cup B)<0$.

The *positive sets* for $\mu$ do form a monotone class; here $A$ is a positive set for $\mu$ if $\mu(E)\ge0$ for every $E\subset A$.

That's wrong. It's true that the sets where $\mu\ge0$ are not closed under finite unions, but I was forgetting the definition of "monotone class". The sets where $\mu\ge0$ are closed under countable increasing unions by "continuity from below". And the magical fact that a signed measure has finite total variation show that it is also continuous from above, hence the sets where $\mu\ge0$ are also  closed under decreasing unions.

Comment: Okay. In some sense, I did the same mistake as you. I was pretty sure that a monotone class is defined to be a system of sets which closed under countable nondecreasing intersections and countable nonincreasing unions, but just to be sure, I've looked the definition up. What I found was the [definition at proofwiki.org](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Monotone_Class) and they don't include the nondecreasing/nonincreasing condition in the definition ...

Comment: However, that seems to be uncommon and we don't need this stronger conditions for the monotone class theorem; which should be the most important usage of monotone classes. As you've said, if $(B_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is nondecreasing and we know that $B_n\in\mathcal M$, then it's easy to see that its union is still in $\mathcal M$. But how do you prove the closedness under nonincreasing unions? Don't see how this is related to the total variation.

Comment: @0xbadf00d You mean nonincreasing intersections. The magic about the total variation being finite is another way of saying that $\mu=\mu_1-\mu_2$, where each $\mu_j\ge0$ is finite. Hence $\mu_j$ is continuous from above - this follows from continuty from below by taking complements.

Comment: Yes, that's the Jordan decomposition of $\mu$. I've actually hoped that you had a more general argument in mind which is still applicable for vector measures of bounded variation on a general Banach space.

Comment: @0xbadf00d We need to decide what the question is. I suspect that if $\mu$ is any vector-valued measure of bounded variation it should be continuous from above, just because if $A_n$ decreases to $A$ and $B_n$ is the complement of $A_n$ then $B_n$ increases to $B$, and $\mu(A_n)=\mu(X)-\mu(B_n)\to\mu(X)-\mu(B)=\mu(A)$.

Comment: The question is as stated and you've answered it perfectly. I was just confused about how you thought we need finiteness of the total variation in order to show the continuity from above. And to be honest, I still don't see it. As you pointed out in your last comment, we can simply reduce the problem to the continuity from below and as discussed before, any vector measure has this property. So, maybe you can elaborate as to why you think there is a problem, unless the measure has bounded variation.